# Open Git Bash with windows batch file and then write in it

Tags: bash, git, batch-file, vagrant

I want to schedule a simple daily task that cd to a folder and then run the command "vagrant up". I've seen a lot of posts saying how to properly open git bash from a batch file but I can't seem to figure out how to write a command in the bash window after it opens up.

I've managed to open de git window, but how can I write something in it when it opens? Shouldn't it be as easy as something like:

```
cd C:\Homestead
start C:\Users\main\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe
vagrant up
```

Comment: The usual way is to store the command `vagrant up` in a file, and run `git-bash.exe filename`. Alternatively, `git-bash.exe -c "vagrant up"` (I hope I got the Windows quoting right); but is there a reason you can't run `vagrant up` from a regular batch script directly?

Comment: The reason is just for the seek of knowledge. Also visual comfort, I work everyday on vagrant and when I'm developing backend I usually need to `vagrant ssh` and I prefer the bash interface to work with. Also I've never done a batch file and I wanted to learn.